# Setting different builds for Maven Dev and Prod

Tags: java, maven, ant

I am migrating from ant to maven.
I need to make the environment specific builds for dev and prod, I have seen many questions related to that but in my case I have some java files which will only goes into prod. How can I use those java fils to separate the builds.

my project structure looks like

```
parent
project A
| src 
| pom
 project B
| src 
| pom   
project C
| src 
| pom
project D
 | src 
 | pom  
Parent-POM
```

Java files which are only used in Prod are the password utilities files.

Please let me know if you have any confusion. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Java files should never different between different environment maybe some property files...

Comment: Than in consequence you need to make a separate module for each environment which contains the differences and creates different packages...That's the cleanest solution so you can also integrate tests for those files in the appropriate modules...Apart from that I would reconsider the architecture and implementation if you really need those differences...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @khmarbaise, nevertheless a dirty approach could be to define the library name as a property and use 2 different profile to decide with library to use.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>${my.library}</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<properties>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
</properties>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <my.library>slf4j-jdk14</my.library>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <my.library>slf4j-log4j12</my.library>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

mvn -P dev  dependency:tree

[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ test ---
[INFO] test:test:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] \- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO]    \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[


mvn -P prod dependency:tree
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ test ---
[INFO] test:test:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] \- org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.7.25:compile
[
```